# how to see if a arraylist is filled or not

Tags: java

Hello I am creating a application that uses arraylists ( practice purposes not real app ) 
I have created a method that gives me the answer of a math but only if the arraylist contains no object. for some reason I always see the else in my if/else construction.

Here is how I check if the array list contains objects

```
public void sluitRegistratie() {

    aantalBezoekers = bezoeker.size();

    if(!(aantalBezoekers >= 0)) {

        String str = "Gemiddelde tijd bezoekers: " + (gesommeerdeTijd / aantalBezoekers);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str);
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bezoekers zijn nog niet weg");
    }

}
```

Comment: can you provide I18N content of the messages =) ?

Comment: Alright people, 7 answers answering the same thing. EDIT: now 6. EDIT: nope, now 7 again!

Comment: Well the messages aren't relevant at all ;))

Comment: @skynorth and none of them needed to know how he populated his list :p

Comment: @weston, Yeah, the funny thing is that their solutions won't help him if he isn't even populating `aantalBezoekers`, which is supposedly the ArrayList in question. And why is this question upvoted 2 times? The point system in SO is so BS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!(aantalBezoekers >= 0)) {
```

Basically means that only execute if when **aantalBezoekers** is **NOT greater than zero**.

If you want to check if your list is of size zero use something like below:

```
if(bezoeker.size()>0){
  System.out.pritnln("bezoeker is greater than zero " + bezoeker..size());
 } 
 else {
  System.out.pritnln("Mahn, my bezoeker is Empty " + bezoeker..size());
  }
```

you could also  simply use [**ArrayList.isEmpty()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#isEmpty%28%29) method to check if an arraylist is empty.

```
if(bezoeker.isEmpty()) {
```

Answer (score 9):

ArrayList has an `isEmpty()` method that will return `true` if the arraylist is empty, `false` otherwise. So it looks like you want `if(bezoeker.isEmpty())...`

Comment: This is the best answer as `isEmpty()` conveys the semantics. It's also potentially more efficient (e.g. linked list).

Answer (score 3):

The size of an ArrayList can never be negative, so your check for !size()>=0 will never be true. Just check if size()==0.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(!(aantalBezoekers >= 0))
```

Is the same as:

```
if(aantalBezoekers < 0)
```

In other words, when the length is less than zero, but this cannot happen.

Answer (score 1):

An `ArrayList` can hold 0 elements at minimum, so `!(aantalBezoekers >= 0)` will always be `false`, and you'll always be in the `else` part.

Answer (score 0):

thats because

`!(aantalBezoekers >= 0)`

means

`not greater than or equal to zero`

which is equivalent to

`less than zero`

which can never happen.